# How to get the real thumbnail size?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to find the real thumbnail size of the posts.

In my blog in the past years I was uploading images (and thumbnails) of 600px width. At the beginning they were even smaller. In the last years they are 1000px width.

I am trying to find a solution in order to correctly use the following [Rich Snippets for Articles](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles):

How can I get the real size of the thumbnail, knowing that different posts can have thumbnails of different sizes?

Is it `wp_get_attachment_image_src`? How to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wp_get_attachment_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) - Retrieve attachment meta field for attachment ID.

```
$image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered );
```

As you can see, the `width` x `height` is nested in `sizes` for each size.

```
Array
   (
       [width] => 2400
       [height] => 1559
       [file] => 2011/12/press_image.jpg
       [sizes] => Array
           (
               [thumbnail] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-150x150.jpg
                       [width] => 150
                       [height] => 150
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [medium] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-4-300x194.jpg
                       [width] => 300
                       [height] => 194
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [large] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-1024x665.jpg
                       [width] => 1024
                       [height] => 665
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
               [post-thumbnail] => Array
                   (
                       [file] => press_image-624x405.jpg
                       [width] => 624
                       [height] => 405
                       [mime-type] => image/jpeg
                   )
           )
       [image_meta] => Array
           (
               [aperture] => 5
               [credit] => 
               [camera] => Canon EOS-1Ds Mark III
               [caption] => 
               [created_timestamp] => 1323190643
               [copyright] => 
               [focal_length] => 35
               [iso] => 800
               [shutter_speed] => 0.016666666666667
               [title] => 
           )
   )
```

Comment: Thank you. This would work fine. What should I put instead of XXX: `<meta itemprop="width" content="<?php XXX ?>">`

Comment: Ask that as a separate question because it's worth it's own answer.

Comment: Be sure to include where you want to use it and what you expect the outcome to be. Also include any examples that might help and I'm sure you can get a good answer.

Comment: Done. If you need more info, please ask, I will provide what I know.